# When should use jQuery Mobile? What is the proper "Use Case"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

According to SO's FAQ, questions addressing *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* are appropriate, so here goes.

I like the UI for jQuery Mobile, but I'm just really getting into Responsive Design whereby my site responds based on screen size (media queries, etc.). ***So where does jQuery Mobile fit into the mix?***

Say for example...

1. I've already designed the "look and feel" of my  site at all my screen sizes.
2. My design does not currently use any of the jQuery Mobile UI elements (at any size).
3. So ...how would my site benefit by using jQuery Mobile?
4. Wouldn't I literally have to redo my whole site to use jQuery Mobile?
5. Or is jQuery Mobile just *(or primarily)* for Mobile ***Apps***?

It's amazing I see so many tutorials that jump straight into the ***HOW*** to use it, but skip right over the ***WHY*** and ***WHEN*** to use it.

Comment: "So where does jQuery Mobile fit into the mix?" It gorges itself on 141KB of precious bandwidth at the very moment that you need to minimise.

Comment: People choose frameworks because the framework solves a particular problem for them. What does jQuery mobile offer? Have a look at their [**home page**](http://jquerymobile.com) - `instead of writing unique apps for each mobile device or OS, the jQuery mobile framework allows you to design a single highly-branded web site or application that will work on all popular smartphone, tablet, and desktop platforms` -- Check out the supported [**devices**](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) That should answer the why. If you need it or not is a different question alltogether.

Comment: The way it looks, going by the work you already have done I wouldn't introduce anything new. If it is not broken don't fix it :) Unless there is a problem you experience jQuery mobile addresses. If not then you should be fine just the way you are.

Comment: Cool. So since I'm not (yet) building mobile "apps", I can skip it for now. Thanks everyone! Now...on to Backbone JS! Cuz, who needs sloppy javascript, eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes jQuery Mobile is just for Mobile Apps, that means it will be used in different web pages to your existing desktop site.

It is possible to create a mobile site using 'responsive design' as you mentioned, but jQuery Mobile is more than this, its designed to be used for a fully dedicated mobile site.

I would look at it like this:

-If you want a web page that looks good on a desktop browser, but also is viewable on a mobile device, use responsive design techniques such as CSS Media Queries

-If you want seperate mobile pages (eg. www.mysite.com/mobile) that mobile devices are forwarded to, jQuery Mobile is for you

Also worth noting, that JQM is optimised for mobile browsers by reducing the number of http requests made by the server (important when you are on a 3G connection etc), something that your normal website probably doesn't do.

Comment: Great comments from all. thanks @DaveB for the detailed breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile is a Framework, it isn't something you just plug into an existing application. If you already have a fully functioning website, jQuery Mobile won't do very much to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery Mobile is to be used mainly in Mobile apps. It gives you basically already created UI which you can easily tweak to your needs to create a cool looking application.